# Stop timer at a certain time in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, timer

I am trying to play and stop the timer at a certain time that i typed in a textbox because i want to play an audio after the time is done.
Can you guys help me out?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Simulate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Simulate.Click
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Show()

    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.fastForward()
    Simulate.Enabled = False




    If TextBox1.Text = 1 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources._1, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = 2 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources._2, AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

If i type say for example 2 seconds, it would take two seconds before the audio file plays.

Answer (score 1):

Drop a timer control on the form and set it to the time interval where you would like it to stop at.  In the timer's tick event disable the timer so that it doesn't fire again, and play your sound.

The timer will fire off X milliseconds after you set it's Enabled property to true.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    tmrAlarm.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds
    tmrAlarm.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub tmrAlarm_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrAlarm.Tick
    tmrAlarm.Enabled = False
    MsgBox("Beep!")
End Sub
```

In this example a message box will pop up 2 seconds after pressing the button.
It requires a `Timer` control to be placed on the form named `tmrAlarm`.

This method will keep your application responsive without having to worry about complex multi-threading issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned about application responsiveness a simple `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeInSeconds * 1000)` will do the trick. This will lock up the application for the sleep time.

If responsiveness is an issue you will need to have the playing of audio occur as a response to a new event you will create. Then you would need to start a new thread that sleeps and after sleep raises your new event.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a timer called "Timer1" for this to work. If textbox contains number "1" then time is set to 1000 milliseconds and timer is started, when 1000ms is up, then it will start playing the sound and then stop the timer.

```
Public Class Form1
        Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
            If TextBox1.Text.Contains("1") Then
                Timer1.Interval = ("1000")
                Timer1.Start()
            ElseIf TextBox1.Text.Contains("2") Then
                Timer1.Interval = ("2000")
                Timer1.Start()
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
            Timer1.Stop()
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources._1, AudioPlayMode.Background)

        End Sub


    End Class
```

Comment: You should not be assigning a string value to `Timer1.Interval`: it requires a Double value: [Timer.Interval Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Also, you should stop the timer before doing anything else - it may not matter in this case as you're playing the file in the background, but if it took more than, say, one second to start playing then the timer tick would fire again.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It should stop the timer right after sound has started playing. So it shouldn't fire again..

Comment: Yes, *after* the sound has started playing. Which could be more than one second after you tell it to start playing. To *make sure* it always behaves correctly, simply move the `Timer1.Stop()` call so that it is the first line of the tick handler.